# Component doesn't use route Joomla 2.5.28

Tags: module, menu, seo, jroute

I'm doing some work on an old joomla website which I can't upgrade at the moment.

I have booking component that has a search **module** which than redirects to component url like this:

```
mysite.com/lang_code/component/vikbooking/?option=com_vikbooking&task=search&...
```

What I usually do when I want to have more control over module placement on such pages is create hidden menu so that component can use that route instead of this generic one, but this time it doesn't work for some reason.

It didn't work with joomla 2.5 for quite a while now so I'm not sure if that is how it was done before 3.x

I also need this so I can set `no index, no follow` on search results for that component. (would rather avoid doing that with robots.txt)

Any idea is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is Ok to create hidden menu items for better content managament.

But, you have to be sure that Itemid is associated with generated Urls.

It is not so obvious how to associate Itemid. Each extension implements its own recipe:

- A single fixed Itemid
- Multiple Itemids, one for each available menu option

If you have a raw Url, you can look for the main extension Itemid (... or hardcode it), or you have to query menu items with a "needle" definition to find the best match (for example, in a category hierarchy).

PD: About "no index, no follow", you can solve it with a simple module override layout customization.

Comment: thanks for your insight, I was thinking of adding robots tag to override but than it would not be in head tag but in body instead so I'm not sure if that's very good idea.

Comment: You can add tags to achieve different objectives.  At link level, crawlers will no follow them.

Comment: Do you maybe mean link attribute?

Comment: Yes, link attrs

Comment: I have ended up modifying component in question and adding `$document = & JFactory :: getDocument(); $document->setMetaData('robots', 'noindex');` to it's main controller.